# Placeholder and NSLocalizedString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nslocalizedstring

I'm trying to translate my application and I find it difficult to translate when there are half a placeholder. I need to locate the following code:

```
[textView1 insertText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ è il %i/%i/%i. Il giorno delle settimana è %@. La Festa è compresa nel calcolo. \n", nomeFesta, giornoFesta, meseFesta, annoFestaModificato, ggSett]];
```

I put in the file localizable.string (English):

```
"festaCompresa" = @"%@ is the %i/%i/%i. the day of the week is %@. The holidays is included in the calculation. \n";
```

Then I edited the piece of code:

```
[textView1 insertText:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"festaCompresaW, @""), nomeFesta, giornoFesta, meseFesta, annoFestaModificato, ggSett]];
```

It does not work.

Comment: How exactly does it not work?

Comment: The screen display is not correct because the word compare: festaCompresaW

Comment: Also there is error in the file. string: Validation failed: the data couldn't be read because it has been corrupted.

Comment: this is the wrong output:NSString è il 200/22678144/1628935280. Il giorno delle settimana è (null). La Festa è compresa nel calcolo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you copy-paste the code? Or did you re-typed it in? Because if you copy-pasted it the problem is there:

```
[textView1 insertText:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"festaCompresaW, @""), nomeFesta, giornoFesta, meseFesta, annoFestaModificato, ggSett]];
```

I suppose it should be

```
[textView1 insertText:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"festaCompresa", @""), nomeFesta, giornoFesta, meseFesta, annoFestaModificato, ggSett]];
```

So basically a `"` instead of `W`.

Also, in Localizable.strings you don't put `@` in front of the quotes, so this:

```
"festaCompresa" = @"%@ is the %i/%i/%i. the day of the week is %@. The holidays is included in the calculation. \n";
```

should be this:

```
"festaCompresa" = "%@ is the %i/%i/%i. the day of the week is %@. The holidays is included in the calculation. \n";
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

Your strings file has a minor error, you've included an `@` as though the string as an `NSString` constant - the file format uses strings in quotes:

```
"festaCompresa" = "%@ is the %i/%i/%i. the day of the week is %@. The holidays is included in the calculation. \n";
```

BTW: when creating format strings for localization you might need to use *positional* formats where each format specification includes the number of the argument. For example:

```
"festaCompresa" = "%1$@ is the %2$i/%3$i/%4$i. the day of the week is %@. The holidays is included in the calculation. \n";
```

This is obviously not required in the above string as the arguments are included in the order they are provided. However in some languages they might need to be in a different order and this is how it is done.